# C# DataGridView: GetCellDisplayRectangle.Location returns wrong values

Tags: c#, datagridview

In a DataGridView, when I adjust, at run time, the with of a column such way that its header's height is modified (because of switching from one line to two lines displaying or vice-versa), the GetCellDisplayRectangle.Location() still indicates the old vertical position of the cell(s). The dataGridView1.Refresh() does not help. Location information is refreshed if, for example, I resize the table dimensions (it is anchored to the form). Why is that? What can I do? Thanks.

Update:

What I want to achieve actually is to have time pickers in the second column of my DataGridView. I know is old topic and I know MSDN example which I don't like because it's huge, cumbersome and not exactly what I need. I use a simple solution: with each new DataGridView line I add DateTimePickers configured as I want to DataGridView controls and I locate them to the desired cell(s) position. This solution almost works: my problem is now that I have to relocate/resize/hide/show the pickers every time I scroll or I change the with/height of the cells.
Code to append DataGridView line:

```
List<DateTimePicker> tplist;  
int index;  
int x, y;  
    private void button_append_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )  
    {  
        DateTimePicker tp;  
        tp = new DateTimePicker();  
        tp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;  
        tp.CustomFormat = "mm:ss";  
        tp.ShowUpDown = true;  
        tp.Value = DateTime.Now.Date;  
        tp.Value = new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1, 0, index, 0 );  
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add( tp );  
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add( new object[] { "line " +  
            Convert.ToString( index ),  
            "val " + Convert.ToString( index ) } );
        Rectangle frame = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle( 1,  
                                     dataGridView1.RowCount - 1, false );
        tp.Size = frame.Size;  
        tp.Location = frame.Location;  
        if( dataGridView1.RowCount <=  
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex +  
            dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount( true ) )
            tp.Visible = true;  
        else tp.Visible = false;  
        tplist.Add( tp );  
        if( tplist.Count == 1 )  
            { x = tplist[ 0 ].Location.X; y = tplist[ 0 ].Location.Y; }  
        index++;  
    }
```

The varible "index" is just for debugging.
Every time I change cell's geometry ory I remove lines or I scroll the DataGridView I call the function:

```
    private void Adjust()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < tplist.Count; i++ )  
        {  
            tplist[ i ].Location = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle( 1, i, true ).Location;  
            if( tplist[ i ].Location.X == 0 )  
            {  
                tplist[ i ].Location = new Point( x, y );
            }  
            else  
            {
                x = tplist[ 0 ].Location.X; y = tplist[ 0 ].Location.Y;
            }  
            tplist[ i ].Size = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle( 1, i, false ).Size;  
            if( i >= dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex && i < dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex + dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount( true ) )  
                tplist[ i ].Visible = true;  
            else tplist[ i ].Visible = false;  
        }
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Note that for first line (for first DataGridView line, not for the top visible line depending on scroll) I have to do some acrobatics specifically. This is because some times GetCellDisplayRectangle.Location returns 0,0 for cell 0,1. Anyway, I actually have problems with GetCellDisplayRectangle.Location for all the cells.

Comment: please share your code, it will be helpful to understand

Comment: Along with the code also mention what you want to achieve. From the description, my guess is, you want to resize the GridView and keep it as it is for next runs. Is that what you are looking for?